# Why is it "Rhine", but "Rhenish"?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, vocabulary, demonyms, german

Being a native German speaker, I just came across the word "Rhenish" (as a translation of German "rheinisch", *belonging to the Rhine*).

I am a bit confused about this, and am at a loss for the proper "language words" to describe it... I have long since ceased to think about either German or English in grammatical terms, going by "feel", and it's just not clicking here.

The German transformation from *Rhein* to *rheinisch* follows the "usual" pattern for such transformations (e.g. *Logik* -> *logisch*).

But the English transformation from *Rhine* to *Rhenish* "feels" awkward, and the result looks like a rather mangled attempt to spell the German *rheinisch*. The dropped / missing "i" looks especially weird. Going with my "gut feeling" I would have expected something like *rhineish*...?

Sorry for not being able to put my finger on it, but... can somebody explain what is "going on" here with *Rhine* -> *Rhenish*?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. There are doubtless different etymologies for the English usages 'Rhine' and 'Rhenish', probably differing at the time the words entered the language.

Comment: Instinct? Suggestion? The Online Etymology Dictionary is considered a standard reference on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I understand the etymology of both *Rhine* and *Rhein* stemming from Latin *Rhenus* (which doesn't have the "i"). I was looking askance at why three out of four cases *have* the "i", but *rhenish* rather surprisingly -- to me -- does not, and if there is any explanation for it other than "well, it doesn't". ;-)

Comment: This is general reference. [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rhenish) has 'Rhenish
"of or belonging to the Rhine" (especially of wine), late 14c., from Anglo-French reneis (13c.), from Medieval Latin Rhenensis, from Rhenus (see Rhine).'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth While it isn't any different from *Mancunian* for Manchester or *Gaditano* for Cadiz, or perhaps *Sinitic* for China, the relative similarity of *Rhine* and *Rhenish* may make it seem that the one is derived from the other, rather than being imported independently. I think the question should stand.

Comment: @DevSolar - History it seems trumps common sense.  I agree with your suggestion that Rhenish is a "...mangled attempt to spell the German rheinisch".  Were we coining the word new today it might well be 'Rhinish'.  In the event I want to use the word today (say, Schumann's 3rd Symphony) I would pronounce 'Rhinish'.  There seems no reason to me to preserve the 'correct' (i.e. wrong) vowel sound besides a mixture of ignorance (of German), Imperial assertiveness ("we'll call it what we like") and perhaps class snobbery (a delight in using upperclass-defining Shibboleths).

Comment: @choster There have been complaints (including one levelled at myself) about questions and answers contributing to mediocrity being submitted here. The lack of use of the obviously relevant general  reference here is surely a close-vote reason. Mitch supplies the required research and states the obvious 'it just seems to be' ' a historical/cultural choice' 'not uncommon in English'.

Comment: @choster: I think you put the finger right on it. I really was trying to figure out how the "transition" from Rhine to rhenish was made, not considering that it might be a case of separate introduction. (Because, I mean, why *should* you? :-D ) I yield, now that I know the answer the question is a bit silly.

Comment: Dev, it's a good question. It doesn't seem to follow usual rules, and so one would naturally wonder if there is some subtler underlying pattern. It turns out that some words really are made up.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps it was because in the past (and English familiarity with Rhenish wine goes back at least to Shakespeare's time) most English speakers would have known the word only from the wine, and I think that's the way a somewhat intoxicated English speaker would try to pronounce "rheinisch".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sometimes, there are phonological rules that tell you what the sound change should be under a modifications.

But here it just seems to be a historical/cultural choice, not uncommon in English, to choose a alternate, classical derivative for that slot (the adjective version/demonym of a place name):

> [Rhenish: "of or belonging to the Rhine" (especially of wine), late 14c., from Anglo-French reneis (13c.), from Medieval Latin Rhenensis, from Rhenus (see Rhine).](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rhenish)

This is similar to Naples->Neapolitan, Venice->Venetian, Norway->[Norwegian](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=norwegian).

So there's no native English sound change to explain the short 'e' in 'rhenish'. It was just an academic choice of a different word altogether.

Comment: Glasgow -> Glaswegian

Comment: @mskfisher Tasmania->Taswegian. Liverpool->Liverpudlian, Manchester->Mancunian, Israel->Sabra, Berlin->Jelly Donut,

Answer (score 9):

Wiktionary gives Rhinish as an alternative form for Rhenish. There are also Rhenian, Rhenic and Rhenane. According to Wiktionary the etymology is:

> From Rhine +‎ -ish (with the first element taking a Latinate form; see
>   Rhenus).

So just in general I guess many words aren't intuitively inflected. The adjective for Wales is Welsh. The adjective describing the geographical area of Flanders is Flemish, and people from there are Flemings. A person from Liverpool is a Liverpudlian. The adjective for Cambridge is not"Cambridgian", but Cantabrigian. God only knows from and through what languages these words have been passed down to us.

If you look at a list of demonyms/ethnonyms you'll see many examples like this.

Comment: Great examples!

Comment: Not just God. Also, dictionaries: e.g. *[Cantabrigian](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cantabrigian)*

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the word *Rhenish*, which ultimately comes from the Latin name of the river *Rhenus*, shows an [older vowel sound](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Rhein) than the early New High German *Rhein*. Both Old High and Middle High German called the river *Rîn*; it was only in early New High German that the diphthong appeared. And there's also the German surname *Rhenisch*, which I assume goes back to a monophthong Rhine river. The *h* that crept into the Latin and NHG words is basically a decoration from the Greek.

*Rhenish* is primarily used in the UK for any German white wine, which Americans call "Rhine wine." American tastes are now sophisticated enough that those who know a little about wine will distinguish it from one that comes from the Mosel/Moselle.

Comment: Just a quick note... *Rhenisch* isn't a common German surname; there are a mere [14 entries of that name in the 2008 phone register](http://www.verwandt.de/karten/absolut/rhenisch.html). ;-) Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: Well, I must have gotten all of them when I googled. The site where one can check such things keeps giving me a 504 error. http://www.verwandt.de/karten/redirecter.php?url=/karten&detail=Rhenisch  Deleted the word _common_.

Comment: It does sometimes give me a 504 as well. It shows regional distribution of names; funnily enough, *Rhenisch* appears mostly in Hannover, Lüneburg and Berlin (none of which is even *close* to the Rhine). ;-)

Comment: I don’t think the first sentence is correct here. _Rhenisch_ is presumably a reasonably modern formation based on Latin _rhēn(ān)us_, whereas _Rhein_ is the inherited form of the name as it was borrowed from some Celtic source (_*Rēnos_ or similar), perhaps more than two millennia ago. The change from OHG _Rîn_ to NHG _R(h)ein_ is a quite regular consequence of the German version of the Great Vowel Shift (which actually predates the GVS). Note that Dutch underwent similar changes, and _Rijn_ represents /rεin/, closer to _Rhine/Rhein_ /raɪn ~ rain/ than to OHG/MHG _Rîn_ /riːn/.

Comment: I agree with Janus: The etymology of the English word isn't older, just its current form. (And that's only the written form, I'm not sure the English pronunciation of Rhenish isn't more recent than the German diphthong.)

Comment: You're forgetting that it was still a monophthong in MHG. OF had a monophthong as did Lat. Ergo the monophthong predates the diphthong in NHG. I'm not saying the English word  is older than the NHG name of the river, only its monophthong.

Comment: @DevSolar It makes sense that the name *Rhenisch* should occur more often far from the Rhine. In those areas, a person could be identified by being from the Rhine area. Near the Rhine, "Rhenisch" would be useless for describing anyone because it describes (nearly) everyone.

Comment: @Karl The diphthong grew out of the monophthong, so yes—the monophthong is older. That doesn’t mean the _etymology_ is older. Those are completely orthogonal concepts; the diphthong doesn’t affect the etymology at all. To the extent that etymologies can ever be meaningfully dated (most sensible way: when did the word become part of the language?), the German word is almost certainly older. English borrowed it from Mediaeval Latin (whose ancestor had borrowed it from Celtic) around 14c., but the predecessor of OHG had borrowed it from the Celts more than a thousand years earlier.

Comment: Also, as @sgf says, the English pronunciation of _Rhenish_ with a ‘long e’ sound (that is, /iː/) is indeed more recent than the German diphthong. Both are the products of erstwhile /eː/ (English) and /iː/ (German) undergoing their respective Great Vowel Shifts, but the German vowel shift happened earlier than the English one—so when the diphthong appeared in German, _Rhenish_ still had /eː/ in English.